# openCV grayscale / color addressing pixel

Tags: c, opencv, iplimage

I have written a block matching algorithm in c++ using opencv for my thesis .
It is working on grayscale pictures and addresses the IPLImage by his absolute pixeladress.

I have to devide the IPLImage in blocks of the same size (8x8 pxls). In order to access the pixel values within the blocks, I compute the pixeladress and access the pixel value in this way:

```
 for (int yBlock = 0; yBlock < maxYBlocks; yBlock++){
    for (int xBlock = 0; yxlock < maxXBlocks; xBlock++){
       for (int yPixel = 0; yPixel < 8; yPixel++){
          for (int xPixel = 0; xPixel < 8; xPixel++){

                pixelAdress = yBlock*imageWidth*8 + xBlock*8 + yPixel*imageWidth + xPixel;

                unsigned char* imagePointer = (unsigned char*)(img->imageData);
                pixelValue = imagePointer[pixelAdress];
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

I do NOT really itterate over rows and cols and it works great!

Now I have a colored IPLImage (no grayscale) and don't know how to access the r, g, b pixelvalues.

I found this on this forum

```
for( row = 0; row < img->height; row++ ){
    for ( col = 0; col < img->width; col++ ){
      b = (int)img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * 3];
      g = (int)img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * 3 + 1];
      r = (int)img->imageData[img->widthStep * row + col * 3 + 2];
}
}
```

but I'm not sure how to use it on my computed pixelAdress. Is it correct just to multiply it by 3 (because I do not iterate over rows and the add 0, 1 or 2? For example:

```
pixelValueR = imagePointer[pixelAdress*3 + 2]; 
pixelValueG = imagePointer[pixelAdress*3 + 1]; 
pixelValueB = imagePointer[pixelAdress*3 + 0];
```

or do I have to use widthStep where I used imageWidth before, like this:

```
pixelAdressR = pixelAdress = yBlock*img->widthStep*8 + xBlock*8*3 + yPixel*img->widthStep + xPixel*3 + 2;
pixelAdressG = pixelAdress = yBlock*img->widthStep*8 + xBlock*8*3 + yPixel*img->widthStep + xPixel*3 + 1;
pixelAdressB = pixelAdress = yBlock*img->widthStep*8 + xBlock*8*3 + yPixel*img->widthStep + xPixel*3;
```

and so access

```
pixelValueR = imagePointer[pixelAdressR];
pixelValueG = imagePointer[pixelAdressG];
pixelValueB = imagePointer[pixelAdressB];
```

Comment: your second version should be correct, since widthStep includes ALL memory needed to "go to the next row" (in bytes).

Be careful, your original code isn't always correct if `imageWidth` is your image's width in pixels, since OpenCV might add additional not used bytes at the end of a column to improve displaying performance (or SSE operations or something else, I'm not sure). That's what `img->widthStep` is made for, so that you can easily address the pixel without knowledge of whether there are additional bytes added or not (and other things like subimaging become trivial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about your whole algorithm and can't test it at the moment, but for IplImages, the memory is aligned as this:

```
1. row
baseadress + 0 = b of [0]
baseadress + 1 = g of [0]
baseadress + 2 = r of [0]
baseadress + 3 = b of [1]
etc

2. row
baseadress + widthStep + 0 = b
baseadress + widthStep + 1 = g
baseadress + widthStep + 2 = r
```

so if you have have `n*m` blocks of size `8x8` unsigned char bgr data and you want to loop over variables `[x,y]` in block `[bx,by]` you can do it like this:

```
baseadress + (by*8+ y_in_block)*widthStep + (bx*8+x)*3 +0 = b
baseadress + (by*8+ y_in_block)*widthStep + (bx*8+x)*3 +1 = g
baseadress + (by*8+ y_in_block)*widthStep + (bx*8+x)*3 +2 = r
```

since row `by*8+y is adress`baseadress + (by*8+ y_in_block)*widthStep`

and column `bx*8+x` is adress offset `(bx*8+x)*3`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was looking for!
I implemented it in this way and it seems like it is working! With baseadress you propably mean the pointer to imagedata, right?

Answer (score 1):

In case of a multi channel `Mat` (BGR in this example) you can access the single pixel by using, as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values)

```
Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
uchar green = intensity.val[1];
uchar red = intensity.val[2];
```

Comment: yeah thanks, but I use an IPLimage and would like to know how to access the rgb values of an absolute pixel adress. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: @user3379319 " but I use an IPLimage "  - DON'T ! the c-api is horribly outdated. and no more developed. stay away from it at any cost.

Comment: I don't want to change my whole algorithm and re-implement it on cvMat just for accessing the rgb values. It will be a lot of work.
Could someone just answer my question, please?

Answer (score 0):

1. For `Mat` (e.g. `Mat img`)

   - Grayscale (`8UC1`):

     ```
     uchar intensity = img.at<uchar>(y, x);
     ```
   - Color image (BGR color ordering, the default format returned by `imread`):

     ```
     Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
     uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
     uchar green = intensity.val[1];
     uchar red = intensity.val[2];
     ```
2. For `IplImage` (e.g. `IplImage* img`)

   - Grayscale:

     ```
     uchar intensity = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, h, w);
     ```
   - Color image:

     ```
     uchar blue = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, y, x*3);
     uchar green = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, y, x*3+1);
     uchar red = CV_IMAGE_ELEM(img, uchar, y, x*3+2);
     ```